# mvc remote validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

Im not sure why my validation is not working if I try to use an integer AdditionalField.

Here's my code(some parts of the code are omitted):

Model

```
    public class PersonViewModelBase
    {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Remote("Checkusername", "Utilities", AdditionalFields = "PersonID")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Controller(Remote)

```
public JsonResult Checkusername(string username, int PersonID)
    {
        //var user = studentRepository.GetStudents()
        //    .Where(a => a.UserName == username.Trim())
        //    .Where(b => b.PersonID != personID);            
        var user = studentRepository.GetStudents().Where(a => a.UserName == username.Trim());
        if (user.Count() > 0)
        {
            return Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", username),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

this remote validation is not being called. But if I try to change the additional field to string the application will call the remotevalidation, though it would become "undefined" because the PersonID is an integer

Answer (score 2):

The AdditionalFields option only sends strings to your action, so you will need to accept it as a string and then manually convert it to an integer.

```
public JsonResult Checkusername(string username, string PersonID)
{
    int personID = Convert.ToInt32(PersonID);

    var user = studentRepository.GetStudents()
        .Where(a => a.UserName == username.Trim())
        .Where(b => b.PersonID != personID); 

    //var user = studentRepository.GetStudents().Where(a => a.UserName == username.Trim());
    if (user.Count() > 0)
    {
       return Json(string.Format("{0} is not available.", username),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not like this, we can not take  the additional field which we have in model.
The solution is take any other field like hidden than assign  the attribute of value = PersonID in your case,  and receive this value in your controller like

View

```
<input type = "hidden" value = "PersonID " id = hiddenID>
```

Model

```
 [Remote("Checkusername", "Utilities", AdditionalFields = "hiddenID ")]
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Checkusername(string username, string hiddenID )
{
  //your code
}
```